# Maven dependency management

Tags: maven-2, merge, branch, freeze

Our project has a dependency like

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>apollo.components.cots</groupId>
    <artifactId>cots-wfs</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

And as far as I understand, maven2 will get the latest artifact for cots-wfs, say <version>2.3-20101111.000000-13</version>

The problem is, when we branch the project, the dependency stays the same, and when other developers release a new cots-wfs say <version>2.3-20101222.000000-13</version> which is not backward compatible, the build is broken.

I am trying to avoid merging the code into the branch, which is painful.

So what do I need to do to "freeze" all the dependencies when I branch the project ?
Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And as far as I understand, maven2 will get the latest artifact for cots-wfs, say `<version>2.3-20101111.000000-13</version>`

It looks like you are using a `SNAPSHOT` dependency for cots-wfs (`2.3-SNAPSHOT`), probably declared in the `dependencyManagement` section.

> The problem is, when we branch the project, the dependency stays the same, and when other developers release a new cots-wfs (...) which is not backward compatible, the build is broken.

Indeed, which is why you should simply not branch an artifact with `SNAPSHOT` dependencies, the build of released artifacts should be reproducible, for ever, and using `SNAPSHOT` dependencies defeats this. The maven release plugin actually forbids releasing a POM having `SNAPSHOT` dependencies.

It is however possible to "lock" `SNAPSHOT` dependencies using [`versions:lock-snapshots`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/lock-snapshots-mojo.html) or, even better, to use the corresponding released version using [`versions:use-releases`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-releases-mojo.html). This is actually the way to go.

By the way, the [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) might help to automate the whole process.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will use version:lock-snapshots. The problem with using released version is that it is very different to that of the latest as the code is evolving quickly. so I branch usually at the mainline.

Answer (score 0):

When you branch means in a sense you are creating a new version of it. Promoting the version number should solve it.

Comment: which version number should be promoted? If i promote the version number of the artifact, the dependencies are still not frozen, meaning problem in building future release if developers release new stuffs

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just add the version tag to the dependency. If your unsure what the current version number is than run "mvn help:effective-pom" to see the pom with all current version numbers.

Comment: Baijens, so this means modifying the version tag for ALL dependencies?

Comment: Or copy the entire effective pom is this is a lot of work for you. You might end up with some unneeded configuration this way.